# Comparing multipart file with exisiting file in directory

Tags: java, file, spring-mvc, multipart

I am trying to compare a Multipart file which is being uploaded by a user to a current file in a directory.
So, if the two files have the same name, I check to see if files are equal.

I have tried using :

> FileUtils.contentEquals(fileMultipart, file2);

The issue is that I cannot compare Multipart file to a file. How do I go about converting the multipart file?

Comment: First convert Multipart file into File then compare.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a multipart file to File?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24339990/how-to-convert-a-multipart-file-to-file)