# Large file upload using FileInputStream and FileOutputStream

Tags: java, grails, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

```
        HttpExchange exchange;
        OutputStream responseBody = null;
        try{
          File fileVal = new File(file);
          InputStream inVal = new FileInputStream(fileVal);
          exchange.sendResponseHeaders(HTTP_OK, fileVal.length());
          responseBody = exchange.getResponseBody();
          int read;
          byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
          while ((readVal = inVal.read(buffer)) != -1){
            responseBody.write(buffer, 0, readVal);
          }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
          //uh-oh, the file doesn't exist
        } catch (IOException e){
          //uh-oh, there was a problem reading the file or sending the response
        } finally {
          if (responseBody != null){
            responseBody.close();
          }
        }
```

I am tring to upload large video file as chunks .while doing the operation I am getting the following error.

```
groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: java.io.File(org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile)
```

any anyone guide me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

The error message descripes the failure perfectly. There is no constructor for the class `File` that accept a parameter of the type `org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile`.

Try using the path to the file you want to open. For example:

```
String path = "/path/to/your/file.txt";
File fileVal = new File(path);
```

Alternatively you can use the `getInputStream()` method from [CommonsMultipartFile](http://static.javadoc.io/org.springframework/spring-web/3.2.12.RELEASE/org/springframework/web/multipart/commons/CommonsMultipartFile.html#getInputStream()).

```
InputStream inVal = file.getInputStream();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File fileVal = new File(file);
```

Here file is org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile type and you are trying to create File object by passing CommonsMultipartFile object in constructor and File class does not have constructor of CommonsMultipartFile type.

[Check here for File Class Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html)

You Need to get Bytes from file object and create a java.io.File object.

[Convert MultiPartFile into File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24339990/how-to-convert-a-multipart-file-to-file)